# Laravel 8 validation required_without

Tags: laravel, validation

I have three Fields

- title
- body
- images[]

the body is required without image, so I did the following:

```
   $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string|max:' . (int) Setting::getValue('titlemaxchars'),
        'body'  => [
            'required_without:images',
            'string',
            'min:'.(int) Setting::getValue('postminchars'),
            'max:'.(int) Setting::getValue('postmaxchars'),
        ],
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('images')) {
        foreach ($request->file('images') as $file) {
            Validator::validate(['photo' => $file], [
                'photo' => ['required', 'file', 'image', 'max:2048'],
            ]);
        }
    }
```

The issue is with the following:

- body.string
- body.min
- body.max

I don't want them to make any error message if there is an Image, and the error message should only appear if there are no images.

Comment: adding another validation field `nullable/sometimes` to body should solve it

Comment: I added nullable but it makes the request successful even if there is no image @FarhanIbnWahid

Comment: another guess: `required_without:images` change this to `required_without:images.*`

Comment: I tried it but not working.

Comment: Add string, min, max to the body. when the image is null

Comment: do you mean to use the if condition?? can you write the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS WORKS FOR ME!

```
 $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|string|max:' . (int) Setting::getValue('titlemaxchars'),
    ]);

    if(!empty($request->hasFile('images'))){
        $request->validate([
            'body'  => 'nullable',
        ]);
    }else{
        $request->validate([
            'body'  => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'min:'.(int) Setting::getValue('postminchars'),
                'max:'.(int) Setting::getValue('postmaxchars'),
            ],
        ]);
    }
```